# regex replacing part of src attribute in visual studio

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio

I'm trying to replace part of a src attribute path using "find & replace" in visual studio 2013 for web using regex. This is what I want it to do.

Original attribute:

```
 src="https://site.oldDomain.com/foofoofoo/screenhunterBLABLABLA"
```

where **foofoofoo** can contain any letter or sign except "
and **BLABLABLA** can contain any letter or sign till the end of the attribute

New attribute:

```
 src="newDomain/screenhunterblablabla"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using visual studio find-replace tool using regex, then I believe this should work for you:

search for pattern:

```
src="https://site\.oldDomain\.com.*?(screenhunter[^"]*")
```

and in the replace box, you can put:

```
src="newDomain/$1
```

$1 is visual studio's way of referencing a capture group ( the part that is in between parenthesis in the regex).

Comment: The search pattern is good, But the target pattern is not working, simply replacing the string itself - src="newDomain/\1